# Localizing Wordpress Post Date

Tags: wordpress, localization, gettext

I'm currently using the gettext function for translating strings on a wordpress site using po files in many languages. Currently all is working great, except I can't seem to figure out the post date. Mainly having a problem getting the month to translate based on which language the user has selected.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php get_the_date(__('F j, Y', 'theme_name')) ?>
```

Withe 'theme_name' being the name of my theme. My question is also won't this just format the way the date is displayed and not actually translate the month? Anyone had to do this, I see people online talking about it, but it's mainly only for one language, while I'm translating for many languages based on which cookie they have stored.

Comment: 'theme_name' is in this case the text domain of your theme (you use it with http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this would only change the order, but not translate any names of the month. Luckily, Wordpress will check for the month and translate it, provided you have the corresponding .mo file for WordPress installed. Unfortunately, Wordpress doesn't cover all translations, so strftime is a better solution here if you really want to go multilingual.

Handling dates in multiple languages is quite annoying, especially if there are multiple spots to configure this. I suggest you simply leave the multilingual part to the multilingual plugins out there.

Answer (score 0):

date_i18n() retrieve the date in localized format, based on timestamp. You need to add a function in functions.php file to rteplace the latin numbers with your local language like this:

```
// Converts Latin digits to Benglai
function latin_to_bengali($number) {
  $latin = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'); 
  $bengali = array('০', '১', '২', '৩', '৪', '৫', '৬', '৭', '৮', '৯');
  return str_replace($latin, $bengali, $number);
}
```

Then add a filter like bellow:

```
// Translates digits of numbers
add_filter('date_i18n', 'latin_to_bengali', 10, 1);
```

That's it. You can check details here: [How to localize Number/Digit in WordPress](http://codecanal.com/localize-numberdigit-wordpress)